# Is the padding for icons in PreferenceHeaders different to PreferenceScreens?

Tags: android

I'm working on two apps - one uses PreferenceHeaders for the settings page, whilst the other entirely uses PreferenceScreens. I've got icons next to the setting items in the PreferenceHeaders screen and it works entirely as I'd expect:

[image]

Unfortunately, in the other app, the use of the `android:icon` attribute has a very different outcome, with lots of padding between the icon and the text:

[image]

Is this just an issue due to the different preference system, or is it caused by something else in the app, and if it is due to the use of `PreferenceScreen`, is there any way to make it mirror the behaviour of `PreferenceHeaders` or should I just switch it?